# how to display build failed with ant

Tags: java, ant

I am using a fake ant(we have our own version of ant that at some point calls the original ant) to run a java applciation. The I run the application I want ant to display `Build Failed`  whenever there is an exception thrown in the code.

Right now what is happening is that if I throw an exception in the code, the ant displays the exception on the terminal but writes `Build Successful` in the end. How can I make the build fail in the case of any exception ? Even if I exit the program by writing 
`System.exit(1)`
 it writes `Java Result: 1` but still writes that the Build was successful. I am using try/catch in the build.xml file but it doesn't help.

The ant target in the build file looks like this.

```
<target name="localhostIsAlive">
    <trycatch>
        <try>
            <java classname="x.y.z.ClassName" fork="true" spawn="${spawnDB}">  
                <arg line="${version}"/>    
                    <classpath>
                        <pathelement location="${basedir}/classes"/>
                    </classpath>                            
            </java>             
        </try>
        <catch>
            <fail message="Some error occured, build should fail"/>
        </catch>
    </trycatch>
</target>
```

Now, what I want is that if there is any exception thrown during the execution of the program, it should display build failed and not build successful.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `failonerror` attribute:

```
<java classname="x.y.z.ClassName" fork="true" spawn="${spawnDB}" failonerror="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
failonerror="true"
```